# Why are the total and free EM fields mixed together?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-fields, polarization, optical-materials

For calculating the work done on a medium by an electric field: $đW = \vec{E} \cdot d\vec{P}$ but for magnetic fields: $đW = \mu_0 \vec{H} \cdot d\vec{M}$. For impedance, $Z = \frac{E}{H}$. Why is the total E field (from both bound and free charges) used, but only the H field (from free currents, not bound currents) used in both of these cases?

Related to this is that the polarization field is generally a function of the total field, $\vec{P}(\vec{E})$, where the magnetization field is generally a function of the free current field, $\vec{M}(\vec{H})$. This has significant implication for calculating material response to waves, particularly for nonlinear response, as the polarization and electric fields need to be found iteratively, but the total magnetic field is found just by adding the applied field and the material response.

To be very clear here, why are bound and free treated differently for electric and magnetic fields? Justification is never given for this in textbooks or on wikipedia, but there must be a reason for it.

Edit:
In response to comment, sources in the vacuum are free charges and currents, and so produce $\vec{D}$ and $\vec{H}$ fields, and since there's no material, they're the same as the total $\vec{E}$ and $\vec{B}$ fields (except for coefficients depending on SI or gaussian units). Inside the material, the $\vec{D}$ and $\vec{H}$ fields induce $\vec{P}$ and $\vec{M}$ fields. First of all, why do we define polarization as a function of the total $\vec{E}$ field, but magnetization as a function of only the free $\vec{H}$ field? This matters because if there's a nonlinear relationship between the electric fields, you have to iteratively find the polarization field, but the magnetization can be found directly because it depends only on the $\vec{H}$ field. Secondly, why do we define work on the material differently with the electric fields vs magnetic fields, with respect to using total, free and bound fields? Thirdly, impedance exists in the vacuum (337 Ohm) as well as in the material. Why do we define impedance with the total electric field but only the free magnetic field? Do we just ignore the contribution of magnetization when it comes to impedance? Feel free to talk about the fields in vacuum vs in material if that's necessary to explain this issue.

Comment: What is the source of your formulae? The correct formulae in terms of $\vec P$ and $\vec M$ should contain the $\vec E_0$ and  $\vec H_0$ fields in the absence of the medium.

Comment: Well for the termodynamic formulae, I used Desloge's Thermal Physics. And the initial formulae include the vacuum part, and then separate it out, where it's ignored, because of interest in the material part, not the vacuum part. This doesn't change my question, where E and H are used, instead of E and B, or D and H.

Comment: If you consider your formulae written in terms of the vacuum fields, there is no problem ($\mu_0 \vec H_0 =  \vec B_0$).

Comment: An additional comment is that the expression for the electric work is correct for the work done by controlling (varying) the potentials of the sources instead of the charges (the two differ by a Legendre transform).

Comment: The whole point is that the book is interested in material response, not the vacuum component. Also I'm not clear what you mean by varying source potential instead of charges by Legendre transform. The point is that in the material, there is an M field, not just H, so why is the total B field not used, and only H? When the total electric field is used in the same situation

Comment: I know that the interest is in the case of the presence of materials. But precisely when describing such a case, the introduction of magnetization and polarization density requires the introduction of the fields in the vacuum. The subject would require more than the space of a comment. I could try to write an answer, although not completely tuned to the present formulation of your question (I have to discuss why the fields in the vacuum enter into his story).